# WebSocket Implementation on a currently running node js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have a node js server running with a react frontend. I want to implement a web-socket connection with socket-io **in the current server** so that I can get real-time updates to the frontend. I don't want it to run on a new server. Pls, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Well, this is generally pretty easy as a webSocket/socket.io connection can "share" an http server that is also serving other types of http requests.  If you show us your relevant server code, we can advise how to add socket.io to that.  This is documented in many places (how to set up a socket.io connection using an existing web server) so it would help if you explained where you got stuck on that or what exactly you didn't understand.

Comment: Socket.io in general WebSockets run over the HTTP for initial handshake. So you can use both in one place. even if you don't use HTTP in the server, sockets will create it for you.
this link might be helpful:
https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io in general WebSockets run over the HTTP for initial handshake.

**In Node Application**

```
// server.js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
socket.on('joined', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('acknowledge', 'Acknowledged');
});

// start server
 http.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
 });
```

**Client-Side**

```
// index.html
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000'); // handshaking to server
//subscribing event
socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    socket.emit('joined', 'Hello World from client'); // send to connected server
});
socket.on('acknowledge', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Happy Coding :)